# Determining MIME type of shared Dropbox intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, dropbox

My app will receive share requests from other apps including Dropbox.  I need to know what kind of file I am receiving, but the mime type I get from Dropbox is "text/plain".  For example:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String sMimeType = i.getType();  //Value = "text/plain"
String sExtraText = i.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);   //Value = "http://db.tt/tH42K3B7"
```

I need to know the difference between images, videos and music files.  Is there any way to determine the file type based on the information in the intent?  Or is there a way to use the Dropbox API to do this?

Thanks,
-Gregg Reno

EDIT: based on the proposed solution from smarx, I found some Android code to do this here:  [Android - Detect URL mime type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664315/android-detect-url-mime-type).  Then added this:

```
sLocation = connection.getHeaderField("location");
mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(sLocation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the norm is here, but I think the `text/plain` refers to the type of data being shared in the intent. (Because it's a URL, plain text seems appropriate.)

From the URL, you can find the MIME type by issuing a `HEAD` request. First resolve the shortened link to get the full share link (in the `Location` header). Then convert the share link to a direct link to the content by replacing `www.dropbox.com` with `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`. (See https://www.dropbox.com/help/201.) Then issue a `HEAd` request and take a look at the `Content-Type` header:

```
$ http HEAD http://db.tt/tH42K3B7
HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2013 15:12:32 GMT
Server: nginx
cache-control: no-cache
location: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dmbdlf56t043miq/2012-02-11%2019.56.17.jpg
pragma: no-cache

$ http HEAD https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dmbdlf56t043miq/2012-02-11%2019.56.17.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-length: 1560063
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2013 15:12:52 GMT
Server: nginx
X-RequestId: a2c4d393af5e0eee80d6f33f68762fd4
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: max-age=0
etag: 1525n
pragma: public
x-dropbox-request-id: 23f50be73831cde4f39a12d5e3f0af78
x-server-response-time: 1149
```

(P.S. The tool I'm using is [httpie](http://httpie.org). You could do the same thing with `curl -I`.)

Comment: Thanks - this pointed me in the right direction.  See my edits above