# Opening video URLs in my app

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-video-player

I've searched a lot about this, but failed to find anything. My goal is to open all URLs with a video file (chosen from a browser). Normally, if all URLs ended with the file extension of the video I.E: `www.example.com/wow.mp4` I could just use this Intent Filter my manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="http"/>
    <data android:scheme="https"/>
    <data android:mimeType="video/*">
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

But that's not the case everywhere, some URLs start like:

```
http://www.videoweed.es/mobile/....17da9f11345a424f02a5
```

and then redirect to the proper link. I would like to know how I can intercept these kind of URLs for videos using the Intent Filter. MXPlayer achieves this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call HTTPConnection module to get the mime type, then use the mime type to launch activity.
You can refer to below code section to get mime type of URL.

You can refer to [Android - Detect URL mime type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664315/android-detect-url-mime-type)

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public static String getMimeType(String url)
{
    String mimeType = null;

    // this is to handle call from main thread
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy prviousThreadPolicy = StrictMode.getThreadPolicy();

    // temporary allow network access main thread
    // in order to get mime type from content-type

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy permitAllPolicy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(permitAllPolicy);

    try
    {
        URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(150);
        connection.setReadTimeout(150);
        mimeType = connection.getContentType();
        Log.i("", "mimeType from content-type "+ mimeType);
    }
    catch (Exception ignored)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        // restore main thread's default network access policy
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(prviousThreadPolicy);
    }

    if(mimeType == null)
    {
        // Our B plan: guessing from from url
        try
        {
            mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(url);
        }
        catch (Exception ignored)
        {
        }
        Log.i("", "mimeType guessed from url "+ mimeType);
    }
    return mimeType;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not the full solution. That code will be run once my app is chosen for the URL, either in from a receiver or within the app itself and if the mimeType is not video, then my will be opened but wont be able to handle the intent. Any idea how to achieve this through the manifest alone?

Comment: I think it's a framework topic now, you should handle it before activity launched, so need framework change to support such functionality.

Comment: Think about it this way, I want my app to be in the chooser dialog dialog, I.E for playing the video. So I cant let the user launch my app only to findout that he chose the wrong link and my app cant do anything about it.